# My code is showing a TypeError:" Cannot read property 'name' of null" in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I am trying to display comments in my campground which runs successfully for the first time but on execution, for the second time, it shows type error. So, I think the error is in the code of database or something related to it.

I tried changing a code little bit but that didn't work and as I am new to nodejs, So I don't currently know where the problem belongs.

// this function creates new campground and comments

```
function seedDB(){  
        Campground.remove({},function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
                console.log('removed campground!');
                data.forEach(element => {
                    Campground.create(element,function(err,campground){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('added a campground!');
                            //Create comment
                            Comment.create({
                                text:'this place is gr8 but I wish there was 
     Internet',
                                author:'homer'
                            },function(err,comment){
                                if(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                }


    else{
                                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                                    campground.save();
                                    console.log('Created a new comment');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });

        });
    }
```

// Schemma for campground

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose'); 
//Schema setup
var campgroundSchemma=new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,  
    description: String,
    comments:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Comment'
    }]
});
```

//code displaying campground and campground

```
    app.get('/campgrounds/:id',function(req,res){


Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate('comments').exec(function(err,foundCampground){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else
                {   console.log(foundCampground);
                    res.render('campgrounds/show',{campground:foundCampground});
                }
            });

        });
```

//dependencies or libraries installed

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.13",
    "npm": "^6.9.0"
  }
```

// if you wanna refer whole code then:
I expect that when I click on the campground it will show me the comment  but instead, it is showing

TypeError:C:\Users\Prashant\Desktop\website\Bootcamp\YelpCamp\v3\views\show.ejs:2

```
 1| <% include partials\header %>
 >> 2| <h1><%=campground.name%></h1>
    3| <img src="<%=campground.image%>">
    4| <p><%=campground.description%></p>
    5| <h2>Comments</h2>
```

Cannot read property 'name' of null

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could go wrong here so I’ll point you in the right direction.

First, the error message is probably generated because the campground is null. This means that you probably aren’t actually finding a campground on your server. This means that either the id is incorrect in your url or seeding did not work properly.

Comment: Actually, the program does run successfully for the first time and even the campground doesn't show null but when I execute it for the second time or execute again then the campground becomes null. And I don't know why its happening cause if there was error then the program shouldn't run in the first time. But instead it runs successfully in the first time without error.